# C++ program hangs for input when non intended

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

i am writing simple school program demonstrating selection sort. I am filling an array
with rand() function, but after entering the length of the array program hangs for input. When i enter some nonsense (char or string) program executes with array of zeros.

Here is the code:

```
 /*Selection sort implementation-
    Autor: Adam Rychter
    09/12/13*/

#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

int* selection_sort(int array[], int length);

int main(void) {
    int length, num;
    int* array;

    cout << "Enter the length of array to sort: ";
    cin  >> length;

    array = new int[length];

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        num = rand();
        array[i] = num;
    }

    int *sorted_array_ptr = selection_sort(array, length);

    system("clear");

    cout << "Sorted array:" <<endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        cout << " " << sorted_array_ptr[i];
    }

    free((void*) array);

    cout << "\n";
}

int* selection_sort(int array[], int length) {

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        int max_index = i;

        for(int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {

            if(array[j] > array[max_index]) {
                max_index = j;
            }
        }

        int tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[max_index];
        array[max_index] = tmp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

I am using G++ compiler with -o3 optimization enabled. Thousand thanks for answers.
Adam Rychter

Comment: Use **new/delete**, **malloc/free** in conjunction.

Comment: To user1920482 - Thanks a lot that worked! Got to write some cheat sheet C vs. C++

Comment: No difference between C and C++. The C input functions such as `getc(stdin)` still work in C++.
Using a different function such as `istream::operator>>()` (that's what you are calling when writing `cin  >> length;`)  will of course use the specific behaviour of that function.

Comment: It looks like the compiler could not allocate the array when free misused. Next time write an exception.

Comment: @user1920482 please post your solution as an answer so it helps other users with the same issue as well :)

Comment: @gldraphael: I've added an answer per your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove this line

```
system("clear");
```

Second, change this,

```
free((void*) array);
```

to,

```
delete []array;
```

If you use `new`, then you'll deallocate the space by `delete`. If you use `malloc`, then you'll deallocate the space by `free`. Mixing up between the two will cause problem.

Prefer to use `new/delete` over `malloc/free`.

According to [C++ FAQ Lite](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/heap.html#fqa-16.4),

> [16.4] Why should I use new instead of trustworthy old malloc()?
>
> FAQ: new/delete call the constructor/destructor; new is type safe,
>   malloc is not; new can be overridden by a class.
>
> FQA: The virtues of new mentioned by the FAQ are not virtues, because
>   constructors, destructors, and operator overloading are garbage (see
>   what happens when you have no garbage collection?), and the type
>   safety issue is really tiny here (normally you have to cast the void*
>   returned by malloc to the right pointer type to assign it to a typed
>   pointer variable, which may be annoying, but far from "unsafe").
>
> Oh, and using trustworthy old malloc makes it possible to use the
>   equally trustworthy & old realloc. Too bad we don't have a shiny new
>   operator renew or something.
>
> Still, new is not bad enough to justify a deviation from the common
>   style used throughout a language, even when the language is C++. In
>   particular, classes with non-trivial constructors will misbehave in
>   fatal ways if you simply malloc the objects. So why not use new
>   throughout the code? People rarely overload operator new, so it
>   probably won't get in your way too much. And if they do overload new,
>   you can always ask them to stop.

Comment: @Abhineet read the comments to the question properly, this has helped the OP. This is the solution.

Comment: Why malloc is not type safe?

Comment: Because malloc will return a chunk of memory after successful allocation. You can change to any type. It will be dangerous if you do it unintentionally.